# Accessing files under .jar in a swing application?

Tags: java, swing, url, jtextcomponent, filepath

Referring to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10043239/803285), I want to ask that how can I read a file in different 
folder into the similar `.jar`.

The folder hierarchy and details are provided with that question.
My main problem is with a line of code:

```
JTextPane textPane = ... //general initialization
textPane.setPage("path/file.html");
```

The problem is I have to keep that file.html in my .jar.

Moreover I would like to know suggestions on this topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Load a resource contained in a jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574809/java-load-a-resource-contained-in-a-jar)

Answer (score 6):

For loading resources in a JAR, you can use `Class.getResource()`. This works equally well when loading from an ordinary folder structure not in a JAR:

```
textPane.setPage(ThisClass.class.getResource("relative/path/to/file.html"));
```

The path here is from whatever folder `ThisClass.class` is in. It is generally better to explicitly name the class rather than using `this.getClass()`, which may end up looking in a different (and unintended) location if this method is called for a subclass.

Comment: Can I use `ClassName.class.getResource()` here?

Comment: I am using: `MyClass.class.getResource("/resources/files/help/file.html");`, this returns correct path with `System.out.println()` but `NullPointerException` with `textPane.setPage()`. . . ??

Comment: @Asif  Using the same `String` would fail, since the raw string is not in itself a valid URL.  1) Get `theURL` using `getResource()` 2) Call `pane.setPage(theURL.toString());`